# Handling the outliers

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I have been trying to handle the outlier for a particular variable. I have tried following code:

```
for feature in X.columns:
    IQR = X[feature].quantile(0.75) - X[feature].quantile(0.25)
    upper = X[feature].quantile(0.75)+(IQR*1.5)
    lower = X[feature].quantile(0.25) - (IQR-1.5)
    X.loc[X[feature]>upper,feature]=X[feature].median()
    X.loc[X[feature]<lower,feature]=X[feature].median()
```

X is a dataframe
upper and lower Means upper boundary and lower boundary.

After running this piece of code, there are still outliers in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also utilise `Z-scores` as a measure to classify outliers

You can calculate Z-score for numeric_cols

```
from scipy.stats import zscore
numeric_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns

# Note that `select_dtypes` returns a data frame. We are selecting only the columns

df_zscore = df[numeric_cols].apply(zscore)
```

Once the z_scores are calculated , you can have a threshold condition to filter the indexes which are above that z-score value

```
threshold = 3
outlier_column = ### The column to check the outliers on

upper_bound_idx = df_zscore[df_zscore[outlier_column] > threshold].index
```

Further which you can filter your original dataframe `df` based on the outlier index values `upper_bound_idx`

outliers = df.loc[upper_bound_idx,outlier_column]

You can choose to drop the outlier indexes as well

```
df = df.drop(index=upper_bound_idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

if the IQR and z-score didn't do it for you, you can try more advanced methods to detect outliers, such as isolation forests, minimum covariance determinant or local outlier factor... this great blog post shows the general gist using sklearn: [blog post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/model-based-outlier-detection-and-removal-in-python/)